# How to rename the sort by text in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I need to rename the default sort by option in magento 1.9.2 category.
These are my magento sort options

- "Position"
- "Date"
- "Name" etc.

And here I want to change "Position" to "Popular" and "Date" to "Newest".
Help me fixing these issues.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Myself and the rest of the community would love to help you out but I think we need a little more information.
What is it you are trying to do? 
Could you please provide some example code for this problem?

Comment: I just want to rename the fields displayed in the sort by from "Position" to "Popular" and "Date" to "Newest" that all, no other codding is required.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you need to override the block that displays the product grid in the category edit screen. This block is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product`.
For this, create a new module. Let's call it `Easylife_Adminhtml` with the following files:
`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Adminhtml.xml` - the module declaration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml` - the module configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_category_tab_product>Easylife_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product</catalog_category_tab_product><!-- override the default block with your ownw-->
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php` - the block override class.

```
<?php 
class Easylife_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_category'=>1));
        }
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
            ->joinField('position',
                'catalog/category_product',
                'position',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                'category_id='.(int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0),
                'left');
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
        }

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if (!$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $this->addColumn('in_category', array(
                'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
                'type'      => 'checkbox',
                'name'      => 'in_category',
                'values'    => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'align'     => 'center',
                'index'     => 'entity_id'
            ));
        }
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
            'sortable'  => true,
            'width'     => '60',
            'index'     => 'entity_id'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('sku', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
            'width'     => '80',
            'index'     => 'sku'
        ));       
        $this->addColumn('position', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Popular'),
            'width'     => '1',
            'type'      => 'number',
            'index'     => 'position',
            'editable'  => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
            //'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_input'
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Go to `_prepareColumns()` and change value of `'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),` to  `'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Popular'),`

Do the same for date too..

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Open file app\design\frontend\your_theme\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml

Find the code :

```
Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Sort By')) ?>">
    <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

In this code "$_order" contains all short by parameters. You can manage your parameter from this.

Example like:

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Sort By')) ?>">
    <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php if ($_order == 'Position'):?>
            <?php echo $this__("Popular")?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_order == 'Date'):?>
            <?php echo $this__("Newest")?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```